# SelectList doesn't show the selected item

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

This is pared down a bit, but essentially I've got a model that looks something like this:

```
public class PersonCreateEditViewModel
{
   public string Title { get; set; }

   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Titles { get; set; }
}
```

and on my edit page I want to display the person's current title in a DropDownList so we can change their title.  That code looks like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Title, new SelectList(Model.Titles, "Value", "Text", Model.Title))
```

and I populate it in my action like so by retrieving a bunch of strings:

```
IEnumerable<SelectList> titles = somelistoftitles.Select(
      c => new SelectListItem
      {
         Value = c,
         Text = c
      };


var viewModel = new PersonCreateEditViewModel()
{
    Title = model.Title,
    Titles = sometitles
};

return View(viewModel);
```

and this populates the DropDownList with the values but does not select the person's current title.  So, I'm obviously doing something wrong here. Looking at the underlying html, I see that the `selected` attribute is not set for the option corresponding to the person's Title.  I *thought* that specifying `Model.Title` there as the third argument would select it.

Ideas?

---

**Update**

I added the setting of the `Selected` property as qntmfred suggested below, and that'll set the right one in the list to true but the `<option>` doesn't have the `selected` attribute on it.

---

**SOLVED**

So, this was subtle.  I just so happened to have a `ViewBag` entry named "Title" - something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Person"
}
```

and this evidently caused the selection to not work since my model has a "Title" property as well.  I solved the problem by renaming the property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**SOLVED**

As I wrote at the end of my question, this wasn't an obvious thing.  I just so happened to have a `ViewBag` entry named "Title" - something like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit Person"
}
```

and this evidently caused the selection to not work since my model has a "Title" property as well.  I solved the problem by renaming the property.

Way too much time wasted on this problem this morning.

Lesson learned.

Comment: It was subtle.  A different one worked fine with the identical code.

Comment: *Kathunk* is the sound of my head hitting my desk. This was very frustrating to track down and I feel that better diagnostics tools in MVC could save a lot of heart ache :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `Selected` property on your `SelectListItem`

```
IEnumerable<SelectList> titles = somelistoftitles.Select(
      c => new SelectListItem
      {
         Value = c,
         Text = c,
         Selected = (c.Equals(model.Title))
      };
```

Comment: Thanks, but while I see that the `Selected` property gets set, for the `SelectListItem` that matches in the controller action, I still don't see the "selected" attribute on the `option` in the resulting html.  I  must be doing something else wrong.